# Get Last Day of the Month with the time set to 00:00:00 on MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I had a query and I am trying to get the yesterday date at 00:00:00 and the previous month date at 00:00:00.
This is my query:

```
SELECT DATEADD( DD,-2, CONVERT( CHAR(8) , getdate() , 112 )) 'Yesterday',
CONVERT( CHAR(8) ,DATEADD(ms,-3, DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0))) , 112 ) 'Last Day of Last Month'
```

The result is as follows:

Yesterday:2015-05-24 00:00:00.000

Last Day of Last Month:20150430

What is wrong here? Even if I move the convert I still getting this format. Is my approach correct?

Comment: you are converting to a char(8) after doing all those date calculations, I think you don't need need to do the convert

Comment: You're falling into a trap of writing unmaintainable code. For `datetime`, the last moment of a day is indeed 3 milliseconds before midnight - but what happens when you switch to `datetime2` in the future - you need to hunt down all of these locations with that "fact" embedded into them. It's far more sensible to use the midnight and switch to using `<` rather than `<=` comparisons, for the end point of a period. The maths is simpler and always correct, no matter what precision you're currently working with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) as yesterday,
    dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0)) as lastDayOfLastMonth
```

For more common date routines, visit this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/) by Lynn Pettis

Comment: Simple and clean solution! Thank you

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Please read the article reference in the answer for some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or above, you can simply use `EOMONTH()` built-in function.

`SELECT CAST(EOMONTH (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -1) AS DATETIME)` will return you `2015-04-30 00:00:00.000`